# Do potential postdoc mentors judge candidates negatively if their advisor in graduate school was denied tenure?

Tags: phd, job, academic-life

I heard some postdocs discussing at a meeting that if assistant professors get denied tenure their students usually can’t find jobs. I think by this they meant academic jobs i.e., postdocs. This seems like an unfair situation since tenure denial seldom has much to do with the student. Is there any truth to this? Are non academic jobs similarly out of reach for such students?

Comment: Since such judgements about candidates are made by individuals, without regulations, there is no way to make a general statement. Surely it happens. Surely some will ignore the issue. But there are a lot of reasons why it is sub-optimal to chose an untenured advisor. This is probably the least important, actually. I mentioned this problem in my answer to your earlier question.

Comment: No field is mentioned in the question.  I wold guess such negative judgment is more common for a literature Ph.D. than for an engineering Ph.D.

Answer (score 17):

I doubt anyone looks at post doc applications and sorts them according to the tenure status of their mentors.

However, there are secondary ways that an advisor's productivity can influence their student.

If a student comes from a high-productivity lab, they are likely to have (co)authored more papers, possibly in better journals. Surely that's not a given for every student, but if someone has failed to get tenure then that suggests they've struggled with productivity and that likely means their students have struggled, too. While it might be possible to account for "advisor bias" and judge students based on what they've done "adjusting for their environment", I think it's far more common to look at output at face value.

A second influence of advisor would be in letters of recommendation. A strong letter from an advisor who is well-known and successful may carry more weight than one from an advisor who has struggled. Again, this is not a direct penalty for having an advisor fail to make tenure, only a side effect.

When positions are scarce compared to applicants, I think it's important to recognize that successful job applications do not come from merely being qualified or capable of doing the job, but rather from competition in comparison against the other applicants. Many qualified candidates may find themselves with no position if their peers outcompete them. There isn't any solution for this if the number of positions cannot be increased and the number of applicants remains high. Different fields have different limitations on available positions and therefore vary widely in competitiveness.

Answer (score 7):

Having been in precisely this situation, I'd worry--but not give up hope!

I concur with both parts of @Byran Krause's answer. Your applications are unlikely to be ignored *because* your advisor did not get tenure, but factors that often lead to your advisor's denial of tenure, like not publishing much/well, may be reflected your CV too. Moreover, the failed tenure process can certainly strain or break relationships, and thus weaken any recommendation that your advisor might provide.

This is not necessarily the case: some places have astonishingly high standards and some profs just don't fit in, personally or intellectually, with their first department. However, even if it is, all isn't lost but you have your work cut out for you.

### The Good News

The good news is that even if it is, **postdocs are often hired *both* for their past output and their future potential**. You therefore need to convince someone you will be successful in the right environment. If your CV alone doesn't do this, you need to find another way to make the case.

This is easiest to do with people who know you already, so I would focus on them, rather than "cold" applications. Collaborators or acquaintances from conferences are good starting points. Hosting a seminar speaker with whom you'd like to work is also a tried-and-true technique. Asking people in your network to introduce you may also help. "He was on track for some great work until the funding ran out" is uselessly gauche coming from you, but can allay some initial skepticism if it comes from a third party.

In a similar vein, I would focus on groups that have recently gotten a large influx of funding, especially if it comes with tight timelines (e.g., DARPA contracts). These groups may be more disposed to hire someone ASAP rather than holding out for the perfect candidate. You can often find about these things from the funders' websites (e.g., [NIH RePORTER](https://reporter.nih.gov) or [CIHR Funding Results](https://cihr-irsc.gc.ca/e/49817.html)).

The rest of your application needs to be top-notch as well. The cover letter needs to clearly and quickly explain why you're applying to *this particular lab*. Your presentation should be polished, and you should have summaries--in various lengths--of your past work and futures ideas.  You need a pat and not-too-negative explanation of anything that "went wrong" in your PhD ("I've learned how important it is to *finish* projects"). Brush up on past work from the group members so you can ask intelligent questions. Send thank yous, etc.

#### The Bad News

So armed, I don't think it will be impossible to find a postdoc. The bad news is that **academia is cumulative** and even if your postdoc is successful, your subsequent applications (e.g., for faculty jobs) probably will not be "curved" to account for a less-successful PhD experience.

So, you will need to hustle. If your PhD lab did not lead to many/strong publications, you will already be on the back foot for funding opportunities, maybe of which are only available for a short time post-PhD. All else being equal, I would pick the faster-moving project: modeling vs. data collection, *in vitro* vs. *in vivo* experiments, etc. You will need to collaborate and network: future funding and job applications will need 3-5 references who are both well-regarded in the field and have seen you succeed. You will need to think about a Plan B and C for your career (indeed, everyone should, and I find that not feeling trapped leads to better work).

Most critically, you will need to make peace with the fact that it will be a longer and harder road for than for others who, mostly by chance, landed in a "better" environment. It is unfair, but anger can only get you so far. I try to channel it by lobbying against things that make it so (e.g., time-since-degree windows) and try to ensure the students around me have a better time than I did.

Good luck and get to work!